# Javascript working only when logged in as admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I added following script to change the date formate of elementor form

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout( function(){
        jQuery('.flatpickr-input').each(function(){ flatpickr( jQuery(this)[0] ).set('dateFormat', 'm/d/Y');});
        jQuery('.elementor-date-field').removeAttr('pattern');
    }, 1000 );
});
</script>
```

and the following function to restrict the past dates

```
// Validate the date field min value from today.
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/validation/date', function( $field, $record, $ajax_handler ) {

    // make sure ts the correct date field
    if ( 'YOUR_FIELD_ID' === $field['id'] ) {
        return;
    }

    $min_allowed_date = strtotime( 'today' );
    


    $form_date = strtotime( $field['value'] );
    if ( $min_allowed_date > $form_date ) {
        $ajax_handler->add_error( $field['id'], 'The Minimum allowed date is, ' . date( 'm/d/Y', $min_allowed_date ) );
    }
    
}, 10, 3 );
```

it is working only when I logged in as admin. But the javascript is not working when I test from an incognito window like a normal site visiter.

please help me to fix this issue

Comment: did you check if jquery is added when you are not logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the javascript to

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      jQuery( document ).ready( function( jQuery ){
            setTimeout( function(){
                  jQuery('.flatpickr-input').each(function(){ flatpickr( $(this)[0] ).set('dateFormat', 'm/d/Y');});
            }, 1000 );
      });
 </script>
```

Now it is working correctly
Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).